# Router canActivate with more than 1 guard

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Does angular(v 4.1.1) router `canActivate` take more than one function

```
{
   path: '',
   component: SomeComponent,
   canActivate: [guard1, guard2, ...]
}
```

should something like that work? If not they why would it be in a list if its suppose to take just one guard

Because I have something similar and even though `guard1` returns `false`, `guard2` will still be executed.

Thanks in advance

Angular 4.1.1

Comment: they are executed one after another

Comment: They are guards and shouldn't be used as worker threads. They should be independent of each other. Otherwise, use resolvers and dependency injection to make them dependent of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work but I believe the guards are executed in parallel not in a sequence. So the second one does not wait until the first one return a value. This should not really affect you if your guards are synchronous, but if they are asynchronous, you will run into this "issue".

If you need your guards to depend on each other, you could separate the common part of the check and all your guards could call that logic. But I think in most cases this should not even be necessary, because if only one of them fails, the route is not activated.

Comment: So what if the second guard depends on the first

Comment: My understanding is that the best practice is to write them as standalone/separate checks and they should not depend on each other.

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks a lot

Comment: With canactivate guards if 1 fails, the route wont be activated. So why would you want to execute the guards in parallel? It makes more sense to let them run in sequence and don't execute the other guards if one fails. The only benefit from running parallel is if all guards will ALWAYS succeed and then you will have a performance gain. But if even 1 of them fails,you are having a performance loss because at the end the route has to wait before all guards are completed to get a definite succeed or fail. So I think it should atleast has the option/setting to configure sequence or parallel